# JSON (Категория -> данные, Категория -> данные)

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

DJANGO rest-framework

Как правильно мне получить JSON в виде:

```
category_id {
    name: 'Пушкин',
    books: {
      книга 1,
      книга 2,
      книга 3
    }

},
category_id {
    name: 'Толстой',
    books: {
      книга 1,
      книга 2,
    }
}
```

Причем запрос должен вернуть не более трех книг на каждую категорию. Возможно ли это сделать бескостыльно?

```
  class Book(models.Model):
            author_id = models.ForeignKey(User, verbose_name = "Создатель", on_delete = models.CASCADE, 
                editable = False, null = True, blank = True)
            category_id = models.ForeignKey('Category', verbose_name = "Категория", on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=1)
            name = models.CharField(verbose_name = 'Имя книги', max_length = 200)
    ...

    class Category(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField('Наименование', max_length = 60, default = '')
    
        def __str__(self):
            return self.name
    
        class Meta:
            verbose_name = 'Категория'
            verbose_name_plural = 'Категории'
```

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете написать свой рендерер и указать его для этой view.

https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/renderers/